# Why does 'apt-get install' suggest packages that I already have?

Tags: install, apt

On Ubuntu Desktop 10.04.1, I have just run `apt-get install` to install a package. Amongst the list of suggested packages is `ssh`.

I'm confused, because I am sure that I already have `ssh` installed:

```
# ssh --version
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
           [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

So...

When `apt-get install` suggests packages, does it take my existing set-up into consideration before making the suggestion? If so, why does it suggest something that I already have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `ssh` program. You don't have the package called `ssh`.

Ubuntu splits ssh into two packages: [`openssh-server`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openssh-server) and [`openssh-client`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openssh-client). The reason for the split is that many people just need the client, not the server. Having the server installed and running when you don't want it isn't just (tiny) a waste of resources, it's a security risk if you have weak passwords.

There's also a package called [`ssh`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ssh). It's intended as a way to say “I just want ssh, all of it, don't bother me with the details”.

APT suggests a package P if one of the packages it's installing suggests P and P isn't installed yet. A suggestion means that

> the listed packages are related to this one and can perhaps enhance its usefulness, but that installing this one without them is perfectly reasonable.

(in the words of the [Debian Policy Manual](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-binarydeps), which defines the packaging format introduced by Debian and also used by Ubuntu).

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer. Also a really useful link to the Debian Policy Manual - i guess if I read that, it'll probably give me a good foundation of knowledge.

Comment: @JW01: You don't need to read that just to use or manage a Debian or Ubuntu system. It's background reading, if you're curious.